# WiX CustomAction shell command

Tags: command-line, wix, installation

I have a CustomAction on my WiX installer, i configured it to execute after install of the files.

```
<CustomAction Id="shellex" Directory="TARGETDIR" Impersonate="no" ExeCommand="cmd.exe /k notepad" Return="check" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
<Custom Action="shellex" After="InstallFiles" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Actually, at the end of install, notepad.exe starts but the installer is blocked at the end.

I would like that notepad starts and finish the installer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want return = asyncNoWait, as it says in the docs:

"Indicates that the custom action will run asyncronously and execution may continue after the installer terminates. "

Comment: Oh I tested this parameter, i thought it didn't work because the installer closes, notepad opens but the console which lanched notepad doesn't close. How to close this console windows ?

Comment: You could try WiX qtexec, quiet exe as it's called, or a few lines of vbscript to run notepad.